# Image in the UINvaigationItem - high resolution

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uinavigationitem

I'm setting the title view to my `UINavigationItem` like this

```
UIImageView *navigationImage = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                   initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = navigationImage;
[navigationImage release];
```

Can I have 2 images, using the header@2x for high resolution, like it happens with icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Did you try it and it didn't work? Try `@"header.png"` instead of `@"header"`.

Comment: How can I know if it is using header or header@2x? I tested in the simulator iOS 4.3, so it should use header@2x, but I don't know how to  check if that's the case.

Comment: @Adriana Start the iOS simulator, and then from the top menu go to "Hardware" -> "Device" and select "iPhone (Retina)". You can switch between the two to test your hi-res graphics.